# ApiDeadlineExceededException using a WebService Client in a GWT WebApp

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I've made a WebService Client using the Eclipse Wizard. It works great when i'm using standar java Classes but when I try to use it in a GWT WebApp I get this error:

```
} catch (ApiProxy.ApiDeadlineExceededException e) {
  throw new SocketException("Socket operation timed out: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

With this message:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Receive() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

**Question 1:** Is there any form to increase this ApiDeadLine timeout? The thing is that i'm debugging and sadly the connection is slow so the answers will last at least 10-20 seconds.

**Question 2:** Should I use another form to communicate with the WebService?

**Question 3:** Should I use some kind of Async threads for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can increase the timeout with this:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.Environment env = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();

env.getAttributes().put("com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.api_deadline_key", 9999 );
```